python selenium select dropdown with a hidden class
I'm a beginner at using python3 and selenium, and I'm trying to click specific value in dropdown options.
I tried using select and actionchains, execute_script with js, xpath, css... etc. but it can't find the element despite the website being fully loaded. I also tried clicking the dropdown for using coordinate, and pressing arrow keys in keychain, but that also hasn't worked.
So I checked the all html, and found that the type of dropdown is hidden.
Is there any way to disable the hidden type or clicking value that I want?
The html code is below:
<input type="hidden" name="txtPosiCd" value="">

<select onchange="" name="txtPosiCd" style="width:150px;" class="textfield" title="직급">

                                
<option value="">전체</option>
                            <option value="11">교수</option>
<option value="12">부교수</option>
<option value="13">조교수</option>
<option value="15">강사</option>
<option value="21">명예교수</option>
</select>

I'm sorry for only attaching the html block; the webpage is only available to its members.
I've tried Googling and searching for solutions, but I couldn't understand the explanations or they were methods I already tried and failed. If there is anything I might have missed, please let me know.

In selenium, you can find the hidden elements but can't operate them with click(), clear(), send_keys() or other methods.
ele = driver.find_element_by_id("example")
print(ele)
ele.send_keys("example") # This will raise ElementNotVisibleException error

However, you can try to operate them with the js code. Assuming you are going to click this hidden link:
<a hidden id="google" href="https://google.com">

You can perform the click operation with the following code.
js = 'document.getElementById("google").click()'
driver.execute_script(js)

And, as per your situation, you can try the following code:
# make the input element show up
js = document.getElementsByName('txtPosiCd')[0].type = ''
driver.execute_script(js)


See, Selenium Doesn't allow us to directly interact with the hidden elements and that's it. In that case, if you try to interact; you'll see "ElementNotInteractable" Exception.
